# Passing parameters from JSP to Controller in URL issue

Tags: java, spring, jsp, url, model-view-controller

I want to update some user’s data and have issue with receiving parameters from JSP dropdown menu. I want to receive entered compId from “Enter PC” block and pass it as a  PathVariable. But it is not seen. If I hardcode **action="${app}/adminEdit.do/${user.userId}/*${any number}*"** it works. So, question is – now to get this parameter from dropdown and set it to path? Thanks in advance.

**Update.jsp snippet**

```
<c:set var="app" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
............
<DIV class="admin_redaction_block">
<sf:form name="adminUserUpdate"
         method="POST"
         modelAttribute="userForm"
         action="${app}/adminEdit.do/${user.userId}/${comp.compId}"
         enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">

    <c:if test="${not empty errorMsg}">
        <div class="error">
            <c:out value="${errorMsg}"/>
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <sf:label path="password"><strong>Enter new password:</strong></sf:label> <br>
    <sf:input path="password" type="text" size="20"/><br>
    <sf:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/>
    <br>
    <sf:label path="email"><strong>Enter new Email:</strong></sf:label> <br>
    <sf:input path="email" type="text" size="20"/><br>
    <sf:errors path="email" cssClass="error"/>

    <strong>PC Assigned:</strong>
    <h3 class="h3">
        <td>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${user.computers!= null && !user.computers['empty']}">
                    <c:forEach items="${user.computers}" var="comp">
                        <c:out value="${comp.pcName}"/>
                    </c:forEach>
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <p class="h3_error">No PC Assigned</p>
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose>
        </td>
    </h3>

    <sf:label path="computers">Enter PC:</sf:label> <br>
    <sf:select path="computers" size="3">
        <c:forEach items="${computers}" var="comp">
            <sf:option value="${comp.compId}">
                <c:out value="${comp.compId}"/>
            </sf:option>
        </c:forEach>
    </sf:select>
    <br> <br>

    <input type="SUBMIT" name="SUBMIT" value="Update User"/>
</sf:form>
```

**Controller**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/adminEdit.do/{userId}/{compId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView updateUserProcess(@ModelAttribute(value = "userForm")
 UserForm userForm,
 @PathVariable("userId") Integer userId,
 @PathVariable("compId") Integer compId,
         BindingResult result, Model model,
         HttpSession session,
         HttpServletRequest request) {
 User user = userService.getUserById(userId);
 model.addAttribute("computers", computerService.getAllComputers());
 ............
 model.addAttribute("userForm", userForm);
 return updatingUser(user, model, userForm);
 }
```

Comment: What type of error you are getting ? and  `If I hardcode action="${app}/adminEdit.do/${user.userId}/${any number}" it works.` -what does it mean ?

Comment: I get 404 error, because path is wrong **localhost:8080/adminEdit.do/2/** - there are no second PathVariable.  About hardcode - it means, that if I set value with myself I get right path **localhost:8080/adminEdit.do/2/5 (or any number)** and it means that to the controller is passed TWO variables. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Means your issue is not passing 2nd parameter correctly, it is blank..

Comment: Can you tell us what is `user` and `comp` here?

Comment: In your first combo `${user.computers}` is there and in second `${computers}`

Comment: @Ninad Pingale Yes, maybe I explained not clear. I have 2nd parameter blank.

Comment: I have **user** entity and **computer** entity. User can have or not computer(s) assigned to him. So, I show what PC is assigned and want to change it.  **${user.computers}** - user's computers, **${computers}** - all available computers.

Comment: So try this `action="${app}/adminEdit.do/${user.userId}/${computers.compId}"`

Comment: I've tried. Problem is that **${computers}** - it is Set of computers. It doesn't have field compId. In this case error is **PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'compId' not found on type java.util.HashSet**. And  **action="${app}/adminEdit.do/${user.userId}/${computers.computer.compId}"** doesn't work too. Exception is **Property 'computer' not found on type java.util.HashSet**  because I don't pass it in the FORM.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot.

You simply forgot that thing are written at different time.

```
<sf:form name="adminUserUpdate" ...
     action="${app}/adminEdit.do/${user.userId}/${comp.compId}" ...>
```

is written at the time of **answering the request that generates the form**. At that time, your app (server side) is simply generating a HTML page, and the `$comp.compid}` does not exist. You can verify it by looking at the HTML source code of the page in your browser.

Later, when you click on the `submit`button, the browser gather data **from input fields** encode all and send it via a POST request to the action URL **without changing it**. Browser does not even know that you wrote `${app}/adminEdit.do/${user.userId}/${comp.compId}` in your jsp : it only recieved a plain text string `localhost:8080/adminEdit.do/2/`

So ... try to get `comp.compid` from an input field of your form using a `<sf:select>` or `<sf:checkboxes>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I tried to set values to the FORM too but they somehow are not setted. Well, thank you very much. I'll work in this way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, after long time of searching I've found now I can pass parameters from JSP to Controller. There are special class **CustomCollectionEditor** which helps pass even multiple select values.
Here is good example https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2009/07/multiple-selects-mit-spring-mvc-2/

And my snippet:

```
 @InitBinder("userForm")
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Set.class, "computers", new CustomCollectionEditor(Set.class) {

            @Override
            protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
                String pcName = null;
                Set<Computer> computerSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();    
                if (element instanceof String && !((String) element).equals("")) {
                    pcName = (String) element;                       
                }                   
                return pcName != null ? computerService.getComputerByName(pcName) : null;
            }
        });
    }
```